# Give KMS access permission to Proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

I want to give the decrypt permission for proxy.

This proxy uses the a key in `secret manager` as username/password store.

and it uses key in `KMS` as Encryption key

This code makes role to acceess the secret manager automatically, but not KMS for decryption.

```
const dbProxy = new rds.DatabaseProxy(this, 'Proxy', {
  proxyTarget: rds.ProxyTarget.fromCluster(dbCluster),
  dbProxyName: `vr-${targetEnv}-rds-proxy`,
  secrets: [dbCluster.secret!],// it makes the role to access the secret manager automatically.
  securityGroups:[proxySecurityGroup],
  requireTLS:false,
  iamAuth:false,
  vpc,
});
const kmsPolicy = new iam.PolicyStatement({
  effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
  actions: ["kms:Decrypt"],
  resources: ["*"],
})

dbProxy.addToRolePolicy(kmsPolicy)
```

However, there comes this error.

Property 'addToRolePolicy' does not exist on type 'DatabaseProxy'

I want to fetch the default created role and add this kmsPolicy

---

I tried this too.

```
const mainEncSecretArn = kms.Key.fromKeyArn(this, "kms-key", "arn:aws:kms:ap-northeast-1:665852837485:key/bf3cf318-1376-44de-a014-181074f4899d");

mainEncSecretArn.grantDecrypt(dbProxy);
```

The error is

```
Argument of type 'DatabaseProxy' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IGrantable'.
Property 'grantPrincipal' is missing in type 'DatabaseProxy' but required in type 'IGrantable'.
```

Comment: Are you sure you want it to be able to decrypt all KMS keys?

Comment: Not every keys, just one key is enough. I think I should put arn instead of *

Comment: IT is just the first trial so I use * , but if I can use `ARN` it's better.

Comment: I updated the article , trying to use access policy for the key itself.

Answer (score 0):

After working today with AWS Support, i was told (verbatim):

> I would suggest explicitly defining the KMS permissions in a IAM policy document rather than using the "fromAliasName" Function.

> I have provided some references that should help you write and attach the necessary KMS permission policy that is equivalent to the one that would have been created by the "fromAliasName" Function

And here is manual version of what support is saying cannot be done with cdk yet:

```
// get your kms key arn:
const kmsKeyArn =
  'arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:123456789012:key/12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890';

// you won't be able to use the default proxy role :(
const proxyRole = new iam.Role(this, 'proxy-role', {
  assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('rds.amazonaws.com'),
});

proxyRole.attachInlinePolicy(
  new iam.Policy(this, 'kms-proxy-decrypt-policy', {
    statements: [
      new iam.PolicyStatement({
        // grant the permission:
        actions: ['kms:Decrypt'],
        // put your kms key arn here:
        resources: [kmsKeyArn],
      }),
    ],
  })
);

const proxy = new rds.DatabaseProxy(this, 'db-proxy', {
  // there is other stuff here:
  ...
  // ..but assign the role here:
  role: proxyRole,
})
```